# Intellij - How to compare two commits with each other?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In the Eclipse IDE I can open the "History" view, select two commits with CTRL, right click and press "Compare with each other". This gives me a directory structure comparison with all filechanges summed up.

Can IntelliJ IDEA do that too?

Comment: What VCS are you using? Anyway, try `alt+9` and "Repository" tab

Comment: I am using Git. I don't see the "Repository" tab. In the "Log" tab I can see my history.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution ?

Comment: check duplicate question, the solution there is correct :)